# Why won't my Javascript functions work?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to edit [this](http://buildinternet.com/2009/01/how-to-make-a-smooth-animated-menu-with-jquery/) JQuery code to work with a PHP, but for some reason, the javascript is not working properly.

**This is the javascript:**

```
function sel(x){
    $(this).stop().animate({height:x},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
}
function desel(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
}
```

**Here is part of the PHP:**

```
    foreach($marcas as $mar){
        foreach($modelos["$mar"] as $mod){
            $tam["$mar"]=$tam["$mar"]+20;
    }
    foreach($marcas as $mar){
        $aux=$tam["$mar"];
        echo "<li style='height: $aux px' onmouseover='sel($aux);' onmouseout='desel();'> <p>$mar</p>";
        foreach($modelos["$mar"] as $mod){
                echo "<p class='subtext'>$mod</p>";
        }
        echo"<br/></li>";
    }
```

Of course, the libraries are both included over the JS code I typed out here, and all the PHP arrays work as intended.

Here is the HTML output on a test run.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 

    <title>Smooth Animated jQuery Menu</title> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animated-menu.css"/> 

    <script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function sel(x){
        $(this).stop().animate({height:x},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
    }
    function desel(){
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
    }
    </script> 
</head> 

<body> 
<ul> 
<li style='height: 80 px' onmouseover='sel(80);' onmouseout='desel();'> 
  <p>VolksWagen</p>
  <p class='subtext'>Bora</p>
  <p class='subtext'>Beetle</p>
  <p class='subtext'>Jetta</p>
  <p class='subtext'>New Beetle</p>
  <br/>
</li>
<li style='height: 20 px' onmouseover='sel(20);' onmouseout='desel();'>
  <p>Jeep</p>
  <p class='subtext'>Cherokee</p>
  <br/>
</li>
<li style='height: 20 px' onmouseover='sel(20);' onmouseout='desel();'>
  <p>Dodge</p>
  <p class='subtext'>Ram 3500</p>
  <br/>
</li>
</ul> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give more information: by "javascript does not work properly" do you mean that it doesn't work at all, or something more specific?

Comment: It's not going to work at all because the functions are not defined in the global scope, and are therefore not visible from the handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason you're using inline handlers?

I'd get rid of those, and use jQuery to set the handlers.

```
<li style='height: 20 px' number = '20'>...</li>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').hover( function() {
        var x = $(this).attr('number');
        $(this).stop().animate({height:x},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
    });
});
```

If the `number` is just the initial height, you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').each(function() {
           // Get int value of inline "height" property
        var x = parseInt(this.style.height);
        $(this).hover( function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({height:x},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
        },
        function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Th <li> are used for the sake generality. To be honest, this is the first piece of code that I write using JQuery. Your response seems interesting, care to explain a bit more to a JQuery noob?

Comment: @serv - Sure. Doing `$('li')` selects all the `<li>` elements on the page. Then calling `.hover()` with two functions for arguments assigns the first function to `mouseenter` and the second to `mouseleave` events. It is a highly maintainable way of managing event handlers and is the common jQuery approach. In the first version above, since you need access to a parameter, I simply assigned the number to a custom attribute on the element `number = 20` or whatever. Then use `$(this).attr('number')` to get the value of that attribute for the element (`this`) that received the event.

Comment: ...The second version is only a little different. It uses `.each()` to iterate over each of the `<li>` elements separately, assigning `.hover()` to each `<li>` (`this`) explicitly. Inside each iteration, it gets the `int` value of the `height` inline style. That value, stored in `x` is used by the `mouseenter` handler. That way you don't need the `number = 20` attribute on each `<li>`.

Comment: ...So with both of these versions, you'd get rid of the inline handlers on the `<li>` elements. `onmouseover='sel(20);' onmouseout='desel();'`

Comment: Thanks. The issue as daniel described... "Your functions may not be bound to the right context (this) when they are being executed. Try passing the element as an argument."


You did help me learn jQuery a bit better though. :)

Comment: @serv - Be aware that you didn't "Accept" Daniel's answer. The one you accepted is essentially identical to mine (except with some mistakes).

Comment: You're right. His size keeps multiplying itself as long as you keep hovering over various <li>'s, and it hasn't finished animating.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Since you defined those functions inside the document ready event handler, they're not in the global scope, and not accessible by the rest of the script. Move those function definitions to the "top level" of the script.</strike>

---

Your functions may not be bound to the right context (`this`) when they are being executed. Try passing the element as an argument.

```
function sel(x, elem){
    $(elem).stop().animate({height:x},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
}
function desel(elem){
    $(elem).stop().animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
}
```

And then change in your PHP script:

```
onmouseover='sel($aux);' onmouseout='desel();
```

to:

```
onmouseover='sel($aux, this);' onmouseout='desel(this);'>
```

Comment: Thanks. This has been addressed; the document.ready was added as a test to see what the problem was, it wasn't supposed to be there.

Comment: @serv-bot: `this` may not be bound to the elements (or maybe it is, I always get confused with inline elements). Try passing the element as an argument to the function, and using that instead of `this`. So... something like `onmouseover = 'sel(80, this)'

Comment: @serv-bot: Why did unmark my answer then? Did I not answer your question: "Why won't my Javascript functions work?"?

Comment: Sorry. While your code really did answer my question, it posed other problems of its own. I wish I could choose both :/ My sincere gratefulness will have to be enough. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions aren't defined in the global scope, so your <li> elements have no function to call. By putting them in the $(document).ready load function, sel and desel are only defined in that scope, so once that function exists, nothing else has access to them anymore.

Michael Grassman's solution will not fix the problem; defining sel and desel in the global scope won't address the root issue, which is your reference to $(this) in each function. You would need access to the event object, which isn't passed when onmouseover is defined as you've done it, or the element itself, which you aren't passing as an argument to sel or desel. You would need to define the handlers as onmouseover="sel(this,80)" (or whatever number it is), and define function sel(obj,x){ $(obj)... } instead. Though it will work, don't do that. jQuery's event handling functions are a much better alternative.

Patrick dw's solution will work. Since your page content is not dynamic (i.e. the <li> elements never change), you can do this:

`$(document).ready(function()

{

  $('li').hover(

    function(){ $(this).stop().animate({height:'auto'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'}) },

    function(){ $(this).stop().animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'}) }

  );

});`


I used height:'auto' in the mouseenter above because it looks like you are attempting to restore the height; using 'auto' dynamically recalculates full height. If you want to use a height you set, try using an expando property or the jQuery.data functions to store the desired height on your <li>s.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are adding the document.ready.

```
function sel(x){
    $(this).stop().animate({height:x},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
}
function desel(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
}
```

should work fine since your onmouseovers and onmouseout are calling the functions.

Document.ready runs code on document loaded.

Comment: ... and also of great significance is the fact that when the functions are declared *inside* the "ready" handler, they're not in the global scope, and thus the references to them in the tags are undefined.

Comment: The HTML output looks fine right? But it just shows me the expanded lists; the JS functions are not functioning at all.


Also, the document.ready I added as a test, to see what the problem was. It wasn't supposed to be there.

Answer (score 0):

The document.ready really isn't a problem here. I think you should use jquery all the way and not define the function calls in your li's if you can.  This ended up working for me:

```
        $(function(){
            $('body ul li').hover(function(){
    var newheight = (Number($(this).css('height').replace('px',''))*5)+'px';
                $(this).stop().animate({
                    height: newheight
                }, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: 600,
                    easing: 'easeOutBounce'
                });
            }, function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({
                    height: '50px'
                }, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: 600,
                    easing: 'easeOutBounce'
                });
            });
        });
```

Which will apply the effect to all li's on the page. You can alter the selector to get more specific or have various heights defined, etc.

Comment: `newheight` will be a different value each time, instead of a fixed value like in the OP's code. And why are you multiplying by `5`?

Comment: just did that cause the example LI i was using had 5 rows, i was animating to 5x the height